# OpenAL: locating freealut or fixing this code

Tags: c++, openal

I am writing a new framework for a game engine, but I'm stuck with one issue, OpenAL.

I'm usually using freealut for this, but i cant find it anywhere, the only site that hosted it is offline, and i don't have any copies of it. I even had to dissect some other guys' project to find openal32.lib. Either my google fu has grown weak, or the vast Internet really doesn't have any copies of it.

I found some example coding showing how to work openAL without the freealut framework, but i cant get it to load in multiple files, so i either have to find out why its not working, or somehow locate freealut, i found some sources for it in github, but at this moment, building freealut from source is out of the question.

I am using visual express c++ 2010 as the ide.

## I modified the code I found, into this:

Basically its three commands to load, play and delete the sound files.
It works fine for one sound file, but when I try to load in more, it stops working.

```
#include "AudioLib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

#include <AL\al.h>
#include <AL\alc.h>


using namespace std;
typedef map <const char *, ALuint > MapType;
MapType soundsbuffer;
MapType soundssource;


int endWithError(char* msg, int error=0)
{
//Display error message in console
cout << msg << "\n";
//system("PAUSE");
return error;
}

vector<const char *> soundslist;


ALCdevice *device;                                                      
ALCcontext *context;   


int loadSound(const char * input) {

FILE *fp;

unsigned char* buf;

    ALuint source;                                                          
ALuint buffer;  

fp = NULL;
fp = fopen(input,"rb");


char type[4];
DWORD size,chunkSize;
short formatType,channels;
DWORD sampleRate, avgBytesPerSec;
short bytesPerSample, bitsPerSample;
DWORD dataSize;


//Check that the WAVE file is OK
fread(type,sizeof(char),4,fp);                                              //Reads the first bytes in the file
if(type[0]!='R' || type[1]!='I' || type[2]!='F' || type[3]!='F')            //Should be "RIFF"
return endWithError ("No RIFF");                                            //Not RIFF

fread(&size, sizeof(DWORD),1,fp);                                           //Continue to read the file
fread(type, sizeof(char),4,fp);                                             //Continue to read the file
if (type[0]!='W' || type[1]!='A' || type[2]!='V' || type[3]!='E')           //This part should be "WAVE"
return endWithError("not WAVE");                                            //Not WAVE

fread(type,sizeof(char),4,fp);                                              //Continue to read the file
if (type[0]!='f' || type[1]!='m' || type[2]!='t' || type[3]!=' ')           //This part should be "fmt "
return endWithError("not fmt ");                                            //Not fmt 

//Now we know that the file is a acceptable WAVE file
//Info about the WAVE data is now read and stored
fread(&chunkSize,sizeof(DWORD),1,fp);
fread(&formatType,sizeof(short),1,fp);
fread(&channels,sizeof(short),1,fp);
fread(&sampleRate,sizeof(DWORD),1,fp);
fread(&avgBytesPerSec,sizeof(DWORD),1,fp);
fread(&bytesPerSample,sizeof(short),1,fp);
fread(&bitsPerSample,sizeof(short),1,fp);

fread(type,sizeof(char),4,fp);
if (type[0]!='d' || type[1]!='a' || type[2]!='t' || type[3]!='a')           //This part should be "data"
return endWithError("Missing DATA");                                        //not data

fread(&dataSize,sizeof(DWORD),1,fp);                                        //The size of the sound data is read

//Display the info about the WAVE file
cout << "Chunk Size: " << chunkSize << "\n";
cout << "Format Type: " << formatType << "\n";
cout << "Channels: " << channels << "\n";
cout << "Sample Rate: " << sampleRate << "\n";
cout << "Average Bytes Per Second: " << avgBytesPerSec << "\n";
cout << "Bytes Per Sample: " << bytesPerSample << "\n";
cout << "Bits Per Sample: " << bitsPerSample << "\n";
cout << "Data Size: " << dataSize << "\n";
    
buf= new unsigned char[dataSize];                            //Allocate memory for the sound data
cout << fread(buf,sizeof(BYTE),dataSize,fp) << " bytes loaded\n";           //Read the sound data and display the 
                                                                            //number of bytes loaded.
                                                                            //Should be the same as the Data Size if OK


//Now OpenAL needs to be initialized 
                                                 //And an OpenAL Context
device = alcOpenDevice(NULL);                                               //Open the device
if(!device) return endWithError("no sound device");                         //Error during device oening
context = alcCreateContext(device, NULL);                                   //Give the device a context
alcMakeContextCurrent(context);                                             //Make the context the current
if(!context) return endWithError("no sound context");                       //Error during context handeling

                                                     //Stores the sound data
ALuint frequency=sampleRate;;                                              //The Sample Rate of the WAVE file
ALenum format=0;                                                            //The audio format (bits per sample, number of channels)

alGenBuffers(1, &buffer);                                                    //Generate one OpenAL Buffer and link to "buffer"
alGenSources(1, &source);                                                   //Generate one OpenAL Source and link to "source"
if(alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR) return endWithError("Error GenSource");     //Error during buffer/source generation

//Figure out the format of the WAVE file
if(bitsPerSample == 8)
{
    if(channels == 1)
        format = AL_FORMAT_MONO8;
    else if(channels == 2)
        format = AL_FORMAT_STEREO8;
}
else if(bitsPerSample == 16)
{
    if(channels == 1)
        format = AL_FORMAT_MONO16;
    else if(channels == 2)
        format = AL_FORMAT_STEREO16;
}
if(!format) return endWithError("Wrong BitPerSample");                      //Not valid format

alBufferData(buffer, format, buf, dataSize, frequency);                    //Store the sound data in the OpenAL Buffer
soundsbuffer[input] = buffer;
soundssource[input] = source;
soundslist.push_back(input);


if(alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR) {
return endWithError("Error loading ALBuffer");                              //Error during buffer loading
}
              fclose(fp); 
       delete[] buf;    

}

int playSound(const char * input) {
    //Sound setting variables
ALfloat SourcePos[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };                                    //Position of the source sound
ALfloat SourceVel[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };                                    //Velocity of the source sound
ALfloat ListenerPos[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };                                  //Position of the listener
ALfloat ListenerVel[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };                                  //Velocity of the listener
ALfloat ListenerOri[] = { 0.0, 0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };                 //Orientation of the listener
                                                                            //First direction vector, then vector pointing up) 
//Listener                                                                               
alListenerfv(AL_POSITION,    ListenerPos);                                  //Set position of the listener
alListenerfv(AL_VELOCITY,    ListenerVel);                                  //Set velocity of the listener
alListenerfv(AL_ORIENTATION, ListenerOri);                                  //Set orientation of the listener

ALuint source = soundssource[input];
ALuint buffer = soundsbuffer[input];

//Source
alSourcei (source, AL_BUFFER,   buffer);                                 //Link the buffer to the source
alSourcef (source, AL_PITCH,    1.0f     );                                 //Set the pitch of the source
alSourcef (source, AL_GAIN,     1.0f     );                                 //Set the gain of the source
alSourcefv(source, AL_POSITION, SourcePos);                                 //Set the position of the source
alSourcefv(source, AL_VELOCITY, SourceVel);                                 //Set the velocity of the source
alSourcei (source, AL_LOOPING,  AL_FALSE );                                 //Set if source is looping sound

//PLAY 
alSourcePlay(source);                                                       //Play the sound buffer linked to the source
if(alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR) return endWithError("Error playing sound"); //Error when playing sound
//system("PAUSE");                                                            //Pause to let the sound play

              

}


void deleteSound() {
    //Clean-up
                                                            //Close the WAVE file
                                                              //Delete the sound data buffer

for(int i = 0; i < soundslist.size(); i++) {
    const char * out = soundslist[i];

alDeleteSources(1, &soundssource[out]);                                                //Delete the OpenAL Source
alDeleteBuffers(1, &soundsbuffer[out]);   
}        
//Delete the OpenAL Buffer
soundslist.clear();

alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);                                                //Make no context current
alcDestroyContext(context);                                                 //Destroy the OpenAL Context
alcCloseDevice(device);      

}
```

So what I'm asking for:
I need either the freealut files, or some help with the code.
Any solutions?

Comment: You can find a 32bit build of freealut here: http://downloads.factorcode.org/dlls/ Is is the `alut.dll` file. I don't think a 64bit build of the freealut windows dll exist anywhere. You just have to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the openal site seems to be partially back online.

For anyone who needs the link: http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Downloads/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=http%3a%2f%2fconnect%2ecreativelabs%2ecom%2fopenal%2fDownloads%2fALUT&FolderCTID=0x01200073059C4C04B4D14B80686126F6C1A2E8